# Git commands on IPython notebook

Tags: git, github, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ssh-keys

I am trying to execute git commands within ipython notebook. I have all the ssh key setup for the github account, and can sucessfully use git commands without my password if I am typing this on terminal. However, when I type this on ipython notebook using the bash command mode it asks for my password. Since the output is static, I have nowhere to enter my password. I don't understand why this would be the case as I though ipython notebook just executes the bash command in terminal.

```
In [*]:!git push
Enter passphrase for key '~/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Does anyone know why I might be seeing this difference?

Thank you.

Comment: I think those commands are run using `sh`, which may be `bash` or a more plain POSIX shell, depending on your system. On my Ubuntu/Debian systems, sh != bash. That might lead to different environment variables etc.

Answer (score 0):

It would be my bet that this is due to a difference between your `.bash_profile` and your `.bashrc` file.

When `bash`is run as a login shell it runs `.bash_profile` and when it isn't it runs `.bashrc` so if they are different you will get a different result.

Personally my `.bashrc` file contains only `source ~/.bash_profile`.